# Function that must take a specific argument with specific value

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, arguments

let's say that in a game project I have an "Enemy" class.
so when you need to create an enemy there is about 5 or let's say 20 enemies all stored in an enum to choose from
and you simply choose your enemy by writing the type of it in the constructor arguments so it will look something like this :

```
enum type
{
    zombie,  monster,  MyDumpAssThatDoesn'tKnowHowToCode, vampire ....
};

Enemy (type)
{
    set the enemy sprite bla bla bla.....
}
```

this seems fine I can instantiate an enemy of whatever type I want easily right ?
but the problem appears when each enemy takes different values say for example :

```
Enemy(type, vector2 Pos) // the zombie also takes the position of the player to attack

Enemy(type, Weapon W) // the monster take a weapon and not a position....
```

so I obviously use different constructors for different types and this is completely fine
however I will get into troubles if I call wrong enemy constructor say if I call

```
Enemy(type, vector2 Pos)
```

and give a monster as a type instead of zombie which I'm not prevented from doing and I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to say here

basically I want to somehow force the argument so when you call this :

```
Enemy(type, vector2 Pos)
```

the enemy type have to be zombie or else you get an error or something

and same thing goes for each enemy constructor. How I'm I supposed to do so ?

Comment: That sounds like you want a class hierarchy rather than `enum`. If you have a `class Zombie: public Enemy`, then this class would only have one constructor that is valid for zombies.

Comment: It seems more to be a design problem if not every enemy could hold a position or a weapon. Maybe think of an empty weapon or an invalid position rather than not allowing to create the enemys. And if you know your constraints, why not check before calling the constructor. The problem is clear, but it sounds like the problem lies deeper in design

Comment: @Yksisarvinen but is it ok to have like 20 class for each enemy type ?

Comment: @Ronaldjoe If you have 20 types of enemies, each with different behaviour, then yes, 20 classes is reasonable. If you can combine some of them (e.g. if zombies an vampyres both have the same behaviour), then it's probably better to create a common class for those (or even a common class from which `Zombie` and `Vampyre` will inherit just to make a difference in sprites for example)